# Why can't I use this input?

Tags: rust

I simplified a lot the code of my real project to narrowing down one issue I cannot understand how to fix.

[Rust Explorer Playground here](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/1v48x8).

The code:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, sync::Arc};

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct PlayerInput {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub location: String,
    // pub team: Box<Team>,
    // others...
}

#[derive(Debug, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct DomainPlayer {
    pub id: String,
    pub name: String,
    pub location: String,
    pub shirt_number: i64,
    // pub team: Box<Team>,
    // others...
}

impl DomainPlayer {
    fn new(id: &str, name: &str, location: &str, shirt_number: i64) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: id.to_string(),
            name: name.to_string(),
            location: location.to_string(),
            shirt_number,
        }
    }
}

pub struct PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'a> {
    // other needed fields here
    pub shirt_next_value: Box<
        dyn FnOnce(&'a str) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<i64, String>> + Send + 'a>>
            + Send
            + Sync
            + 'a,
    >,
}

async fn player_create<'a>(
    pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>,
    _team_id: &'a str,
    _input: &'a PlayerInput,
    lambda: &(dyn for<'b> Fn(
        PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'b>,
    ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<DomainPlayer, String>> + Send + 'b>>
          + Sync
          + '_),
) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
    let mut tx = pool.begin().await.unwrap();

    let domain_player = lambda(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs {
        shirt_next_value: Box::new(|model: &str| {
            Box::pin(shirt_get_next_and_increase(&mut tx, model))
        }),
    })
    .await?;

    let res =
        sqlx::query_as::<_, DomainPlayer>("INSERT INTO player (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *")
            .bind(domain_player.id)
            .bind(domain_player.shirt_number)
            .fetch_one(&mut *tx)
            .await
            .unwrap();

    Ok(res)
}

async fn shirt_get_next_and_increase(
    tx: &mut sqlx::PgConnection,
    model: &str,
) -> Result<i64, String> {
    // Here I'm awaiting an async call for DB operations using the same DB transacion of the caller (_tx)...
    dbg!(tx);

    // use model here...
    dbg!(model);

    let res = 123;

    Ok(res)
}

pub async fn handle(pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>, input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
    let res = player_create(pool, "team", input, &|args| {
        let input = input;

        Box::pin(async move {
            let shirt_number = (args.shirt_next_value)("player").await?;

            let o = DomainPlayer::new(&input.id, &input.name, &input.location, shirt_number);

            Ok(o)
        })
    })
    .await?;

    Ok(res)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let pool = Arc::new(sqlx::PgPool::connect("fake_url").await.unwrap());

    let new_player_input = PlayerInput {
        id: "abc".to_string(),
        name: "John".to_string(),
        location: "Boston".to_string(),
    };

    let player = handle(pool.clone(), &new_player_input).await?;

    dbg!(player);

    Ok(())
}
```

The error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:104:9
    |
100 |   pub async fn handle(pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>, input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
    |                                                       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
104 | /         Box::pin(async move {
105 | |             let shirt_number = (args.shirt_next_value)("player").await?;
106 | |
107 | |             let o = DomainPlayer::new(&input.id, &input.name, &input.location, shirt_number);
108 | |
109 | |             Ok(o)
110 | |         })
    | |__________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Comment: Same as on most of your last few questions, there is a lot of code here that is not related to the error you posted can you please provide a [***minimal*** reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I narrowed it down, really. From 200 to 100 LOC. I don't really know how to further go.

Comment: dunno rust but looks like a fair question effort so --1

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite your `handle` a little bit, to make it easier to explain:

```rust
pub async fn handle(pool: Arc<sqlx::PgPool>, input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<DomainPlayer, String> {
    let lambdaref: &(dyn for<'b> Fn(PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'b>) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<DomainPlayer, String>> + Send + 'b>> + Sync) = &|args: PlayerCreateLambdaArgs| {
        let input = input;

        Box::pin(async move {
            let shirt_number = (args.shirt_next_value)("player").await?;

            let o = DomainPlayer::new(&input.id, &input.name, &input.location, shirt_number);

            Ok(o)
        })
    };

    let res = player_create(pool, "team", input, lambdaref)
    .await?;

    Ok(res)
}
```

so `lambdaref` references a lambda, which takes a `PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'b>` and produces a a boxed future guaranteed to live at least as long as `'b`.

And it also captures `input` which we know lives at least as long as `'a`.

So we can deduce, that `'a` must live at least as long as `'b` otherwise the boxed future couldn't live at least as long as `'b`, as it needs access to `input`, too.

But `'b` is not yet determined and can be chosen by the caller of the lamba. The caller of the lambda could choose to use a `PlayerCreateLambdaArgs<'static>` and therefore choose `'b` to be `'static`.

So rustc has to demand `'a` to be `'static` so the lambda can be called with every possible `'b`.

If you can change `player_create` and `PlayerCreateLambdaArgs`, then you can
side step this issue. `player_create` already gets `input` and could just
hand it down to the lamba inside `PlayerCreateLambdaArgs`, too.

Like in https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/8vonk0

If you don't mind me saying, it looks all a bit convoluted, what is it, you really want to achieve?

Comment: First of all: THANK YOU! As you can imagine this is a simplified version of my real project code. This convoluted code is because I'm using a "Clean Code Architecture" approach where (despite the name) I have `adapters / ports / app (aka controllers) / domain` modules. This approach is coming from my Golang codebase which is obviously simpler to write (no lifetimes there). The `handle` function is the code in the controller: it doesn't care about persistence (DB) or other repositories: it only executes business logic.

Comment: So I'm using this pattern because it's very easy (in Go) to pass DB transaction within `player_create` function (I borrowed this idea from https://threedots.tech/post/repository-pattern-in-go). Is it more clear now? Can you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: I can change whatever I want.

Comment: That is a broad topic and I am far from an expert on clean code architecture. But note that you get a `sqlx::Transaction<'static, sqlx::Postgres>` from `pool.begin().await.unrwap()`. So its just a value with no special lifetime attached, you can just pass it around. So an async function should take it as value (owned) and just return it in their return value. Functions creating futures need to donate it to the future, which returns it in their return value. That way you don't need complicated lifetime logic.

Comment: Otherwise maybe take a look at https://alexis-lozano.com/hexagonal-architecture-in-rust-1/
Such a Traits & Generics based approach might be viable, if you don't need runtime polymorphism for the components making up the clean architecture.

Comment: `Functions creating futures need to donate it to the future` A novel title! LOL. This is interesting tough. Can you please use this idea in the code I posted? This will simplify a lot I think... https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/1v48x8